# Atualizar DIV Automaticamente (autorefresh) sem atualizar página toda

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de atualizar apenas uma `div` automaticamente a cada `x` segundos sem ter que atualizar a pagina toda isso seria possível?

Comment: voce diz... como se fosse um chat?Ou atualizar em que sentido?

Comment: isso como se fosse um chat

Comment: Entendi. Existem varias formas de fazer, algumas exigindo mais do servidor outras não. Estou sem tempo agora, mas se nao pintar nenhuma resposta ai. Eu respondo

Comment: Isso aí cura com `Websocket`.

Comment: Acredito que já haja varias respostas para isso, basta ver qual se adapta melhor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=atualizar+sem+refresh

Comment: Está usando PHP, RubyOnRails, Node.js ou asp.net?

Comment: Estou  usando PHP

Comment: Se a resposta que marquei como dup não resolver tente estas respostas http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=atualizar+sem+refresh+%5Bphp%5D a maioria é igual ao seu problema.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" > Tipo isso mais apenas em uma div na mesma pagina

Comment: @HemersonPrestes não está sabendo dizer o que quer. Mano, `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" > ` vai recarregar a bagaça toda. Não dá pra usar isso da forma que você pede na questão. Se vc quer que essa `div` mude ao digitar texto ou clicar algo (evento), então sua pergunta está duplicada e tem que ser fechada.

Comment: Exemplo estou com a pagina aberta com o dreamwaver aberto, ao mudar o texto na div pelo dreamwaver muda o texto na tela do navegador apenas, muda o texto daquela div que estou alterando pelo dreamwaver

Comment: @HemersonPrestes não só ajax resolve (ou qualquer coisa que faça o processo em background, mas é mais complexo que ajax, então ajax é o caminho mais facil basta estudar).

Comment: @HemersonPrestes Dreamwaver é editor, você tem que aprender o que é front-end, back-end e de preferencia entender o que é HTTP. Sem saber HTTP tecnicamente você não sabe o que é site.

Comment: Será que ele está falando em criar um módulo para o navegador (extensão) que monitora os arquivos do código fonte em um ambiente de desenvolvimento e, quando estão são modificados/savos, o navegador atualiza apenas o elemento modificado, sem precisar dar refresh na página toda (tipo o hot module replacement do webpack)? Ou, no mínimo, um refresh automático, para o desenvolvedor não ficar dando F5.

Comment: @mrlew ae seria motivo para fechamento *"não está clara"*.

Answer (score 2):

Atualizar uma `div` automaticamente a cada 3 segundos usando `HTML` e `JavaScript` sem atualizar a página toda:

```js
 $(function() {
   setTime();
   function setTime() {
      var date = new Date().getTime();
      var string = "Timestamp: "+date;
      setTimeout(setTime, 3000);
      $('#setTime').html(string);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="setTime"></div>
```

Comment: Gostaria de editar , e mudar conforme eu coloque o texto entre as tags exemplo <div id="setTime"> aqui eu editei</div>

Comment: Mano, se decide... É automático ou não é?

Comment: Automaticamente

Comment: Mais nao dentro do javascritp eu vou alterar entre a div

Comment: Mas ` $('#setTime').html(string);` está alterando o conteúdo da `<div>`. Não tem nada sendo alterado no javascript...

Comment: Eu queria tipo assim <div id="setTime"> original</div>  na tela palavra original ai vou mudar <div id="setTime"> mudei </div> e muda-se na tela para a palavra mudei entendeu

Comment: Só pra constar: se você precisa digitar, então **não é automático**, e não pode ser "a cada x segundos" como você perguntou. Edita, ou faz outra pergunta ;)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52108/discussion-between-hemerson-prestes-and-shutupmagda).

Comment: Vc pode entrar no chat ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" > Tipo isso mais apenas em uma div

Answer (score 1):

Existem muitos frameworks e bibliotecas que podem lhe ajudar a manipular o **DOM**, como: JQuery, AngularJS, EmberJS, ReactJS, etc. Não irei entrar em detalhes sobre eles, mas basicamente você pode adicionar ouvintes de eventos específicos a elementos que você queira manipular. Aqui está um exemplo de como alterar o texto de uma div adicionando um ouvinte para o evento de **clique**. Quanto a atualizar a cada *X* tempo, você pode usar a função `setInterval`, você pode ver mais detalhes sobre ela na [documentação](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Espero ter ajudado. :)

```
<div id="myId">Original</div>

<script>
    var div = document.getElementById("myId");

    // Adicionando ouvinte de clique
    div.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        div.innerHTML = "Alterado =)";
    });

    // Criando um intervalo
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        div.innerHTML = date.toLocaleTimeString();

        if (date.getSeconds() % 5 == 0) {
            div.innerHTML = "Intervalo cancelado :)";
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000/* 1s */);

</script>
```

Comment: Acho que ele não quer ficar clicando a parada... Ele quer que seja automático...

Comment: Isso mano obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

montei um exemplo bem simples, vc clica na div e ela muda.

Num caso mais real vc deveria chamar via ajax um backend e este te retornar o conteúdo, espero ter ajudado.

```
<body>
    <div id=teste onclick="changeMe()"> meu texto original </div>
    <div id="meuReload" style="border: solid 1px">
                3
    </div>
    <script>
        function changeMe(){
            document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = "alterei a div";
            n=0;
            setInterval(function(){ 
            n=n+1;
            document.getElementById("meuReload").innerHTML = "alterando a outra div"+n; }, 2000);
        }           
    </script>
</body>
```

Abs

Comment: OI mano editei a pergunta tinha interpretado a vcs errado na verdade gostaria isso automaticamente  um (auto refresh na div a cada x segundos)

Comment: Alterei para o que vc pediu basta usar o setInterval() o resto é só demonstração.

Comment: Testei mano nada desculpa nao manjo nada de javascritp sei basicos dos basicos

Comment: Voce chegou a testar clicando no testo "meu texto original"? A cada 2 segundos é para mudar a div de baixo.