# Como atualizar uma div a cada x segundos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Segue uma parte do código html, eu preciso atualizar essa div (#linha1) a cada x segundos sem usar php. Pode ser com jquery, ajax, js ou todos juntos.
Não quero simplesmente mudar uma div ("div alterada"), ela é dinâmica, pega dados de um controller. Quero dar um refresh para recarregar os dados, caso teve algum insert, delete ou update no banco.

```
<div id="linha1" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Dados Veículo</h2>
        <table id="tabela">
            <tr>
                <td>Serial</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.serial}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.data}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hora</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.hora}" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eixos</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.axlNumber}" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PBT</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.pbt}" /> </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Classe</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.classe}" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Placa</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.placa}" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Speed</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{realtime.speed}" /> </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se perceber Inglês, tem aqui a resposta: https://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/

Comment: já pensou em usar setTimeout?

Comment: Tem esta em Português, se fizesse um pouco de pesquisa, já tinha a resolução... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178662/atualizar-div-automaticamente-autorefresh-sem-atualizar-p%C3%A1gina-toda

Comment: pois é, eu segui esse topico já, mas ele nao carrega a div apenas, ele carrega a pgina inteira, nao sei o que estou fazendo de errado

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Atualizar DIV Automaticamente (autorefresh) sem atualizar página toda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178662/atualizar-div-automaticamente-autorefresh-sem-atualizar-p%c3%a1gina-toda)

Answer (score 2):

Faça uma chamada ajax a cada x segundos e execute o seu código para atualizar a div.

```js
var time = 1000; // 1s

setTimeout(function(){ 
  // Seu código
}, time);
```