# Carregar comentário de resposta com AJAX sem atualizar a página

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, funções

Estou enviando comentários com o AJAX e em seguida carregando-o na resposta, funciona bem, exceto que o link de resposta não está sendo processado na página, depois de clica em publicar resposta a pagina esta sendo atualizada e retornando a resposta, mas o certo seria a pagina não atualizar e publicar a resposta.

> functions.php

```
# COMENTÁRIOS AJAX
function your_theme_slug_comments($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    if ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) {
        $tag       = 'div';
        $add_below = 'comment';
    } else {
        $tag       = 'li';
        $add_below = 'comment';
    } ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> <?php echo $tag; ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">

        <div class="comment-wrap">
            <div class="comment-img">
                <?php get_avatar($comment,$args['avatar_size'],null,null,array('class' => array('img-responsive', 'img-circle') )); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-body">
                <h4 class="comment-author"><?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?></h4>
                <span class="comment-date"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></span>
                <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') { ?><em><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php _e('Comentário aguardando aprovação'); ?></em><br /><?php } ?>
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
                <span class="comment-reply"><?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array('reply_text' => 'Responder', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth'  => $args['max_depth']))); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php
}
```

> comments.php

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) { return; } ?>
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
    <?php if ( have_comments() ) { ?>
        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'avatar_size' => 70, 'style' => 'ul', 'callback' => 'your_theme_slug_comments', 'type' => 'all' ) ); ?>
        </ol>
        <?php the_comments_pagination( array( 'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous') . '</span>', 'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next') . '</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ) ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) { ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Os comentários estão fechados.'); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php comment_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é atualizar apenas a `<div>` que está carregando os comentários, inserindo o mesmo html e puxando o php.

O código para isso em JQuery é:

`$(function() {
   setTime();
   function setTime() {
      var date = new Date().getTime();
      var string = "Timestamp: "+date;
      setTimeout(setTime, 3000);
      $('#comments').html(some.code.php);
   }
 });`

[Source](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178662/atualizar-div-automaticamente-autorefresh-sem-atualizar-p%C3%A1gina-toda)

Tendo em vista que nessa função acima o tempo é de 3000 milissegundos, ou três segundos, você pode manipular o tempo.

Comment: obrigado por responder, testei mas não funcionou, quando uma nova resposta e enviada a página redireciona para o id da resposta, ex.: http://dominio.com/nomedopost/#comment-1, ou seja, a pagina atualiza de qualquer maneira